# What password requirements exist for new users?

Tags: templating, registration, password

My site contains a [front-end registration form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form). New users will be automatically activated, and can begin using their account immediately.

**What password requirements exist?**

I vaguely remember a 6-character minimum... Is that accurate, and are there any other requirements to be aware of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Craft 2**:

By default Craft enforces a 6 character minimum as the only password requirement, but as of [Craft 2.3](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2615), a plugin can now listen for the [users.onBeforeSetPassword](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onBeforeSetPassword) event to enforce any password requirements it wants for newly set/changed passwords and set `$performAction = false` to cancel the action with any validation errors returned on the UserModel.

**Craft 3**:

This has changed quite a bit for Craft 3... here is how you would pull it off:

```
use craft\elements\User;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\base\ModelEvent;

Event::on(User::class, User::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE, function(ModelEvent $event) {
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $event->sender;

    if ($user->newPassword !== null) {
        $validates = $this->validateNewPassword($user->newPassword);

        if (!$validates) {
            $user->addError('newPassword', Craft::t('plugin-handle', 'Invalid password'));
            $event->isValid = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear we'll be able to customize this more in the future!

Comment: Has this changed at all in the past year? We would like to define password requirements that would apply everywhere (new user front-end registration, front-end password update form, email reset link)

Comment: @JohnO Indeed... updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!