# Password should fail on front-end registration form

Tags: error-message, error, registration, password

**Update** For anyone else having a braindead moment, registration form errors only display for `password` when logged out. If you're logged in as admin they won't display.

User posted even though using an empty password. According to [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/what-password-requirements-exist-for-new-users) and [this form template](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) an empty password box (or less than 6 characters) should fail and return an error yes?

```
<div class="grid-item 1/1">
    <div class="grid-item xs-1/1 md-1/3 mb">
        <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label></h3>
        <input id="password" class="form-input" type="password" name="password">
      <small>6 characters or more — keep it secret, keep it safe.</small>

          {% if account is defined %}
            {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}
          {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</div>
```

Screenshots:

[image: No error messages]

[image]

Comment: This is for new user registration? Can you share the entire form?

Comment: Yes, new user registration. I've also tried the exact same form from the docs, this one is only modifying the layout and registration button `value`. Should there be a password `value` with `{%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.password }}"{% endif %}`?

Comment: `firstName` and `lastName` don't return errors either, but I assume that's because they're not required in CP and they do post. Would it be wise to use a custom jQuery plugin, or is there a bug with your error console?

Comment: Scrap this, I've been logged in as admin. Password error only gets flagged when creating an account as a regular new user. Oops.

Comment: I'm only laughing because I've done the same thing myself a dozen times. Wanna go ahead and add that as the official answer?

Comment: Haha, yeah I will do! And to the Mandrill post also, which is the same deal. Maybe you need a console error for `stop being a derp` :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registration form errors **only display for `password` when logged out**. If you're logged in as admin they won't display.